# Comprobar que existe un dato e insertar en ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, clase, objeto

estoy con una práctica de clase y no sé cómo hacer que me compruebe que ya existe un valor en el ArrayList antes de insertar nuevos. Además, veo que cada vez que inserto valores, veo que reemplaza los anteriores con los mismos datos.

Mi idea es que antes de insertar los datos, compruebe si ya hay una clave igual que la insertada. Además, no sé por qué cuando lo ejecuto y hago que imprima el ArrayList salen todos los valores iguales.

**Clase CancionDAO: ** recibe un ArrayList sobre el que tiene que comparar la clave, además de insertar valores si la clave es distinta a todas las demás de la lista.

Código clase CancionDAO:

```
public class CancionDAO {
static String clave = null;
static String interprete = null;
static String autor = null;
static String album = null;
static int duracion = 0;

CancionDAO(String clave, String interprete, String autor, String album, int duracion) {
    this.clave = clave;
    this.interprete = interprete;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.album = album;
    this.duracion = duracion;
}



void insertarCancion(ArrayList canciones, CancionDAO utils) {
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean igual = false;
    Cancion insert = new Cancion();

    System.out.print("Inserta la clave: ");
    clave = lector.next();

    if(canciones.contains(clave)){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Clave repetida");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Inserta el interprete: ");
        interprete = lector.next();
        System.out.print("Inserta el autor: ");
        autor = lector.next();
        System.out.print("Inserta el album: ");
        album = lector.next();
        System.out.print("Inserta la duracion: ");
        duracion = sc.nextInt();
        insert.setClave(clave);
        insert.setInterprete(interprete);
        insert.setAutor(autor);
        insert.setAlbum(album);
        insert.setDuracion(duracion);
        canciones.add(insert);
        for(Object o : canciones){
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: El método `contains` invoca internamente al método `equals` de la clase `Cancion`, como la clase nunca le hizo un override, llama al `equals` de la clase base (es decir, la clase `Object`) y hace que devuelva `false`. **Solución:** Sobrescribe el método `equals` en la clase `Cancion` y agrega la condición para poder comparar los objetos.

Answer (score 0):

No te funciona por que estas comparando si el **ArrayList contiene un string** (el que almacenas en tu variable clave), pero tu **ArrayList contiene una colección de objetos de la clase CancionDao**

Se me ocurre hacer algún método que recorra tu ArrayList y verifique si existe un objeto con la clave

```
boolean ExisteClave(ArrayList canciones, String clave) {
    for(int x = 0; x < canciones.size(); x++) {
        if(canciones[x].GetClave().equals(clave))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Para tu clase CancionDAO es necesario tener el método **GetClave** el que debe retornar el atributo **clave**

Con esos metodos implementados, debes remplazar tu linea de código

```
if(canciones.contains(clave)){
```

Por esta:

```
if(ExisteClave(canciones, clave)){
```